# How to rectify Typescript compilation error TS5012

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have typescript installed globally on my machine but when i run "tsc using-ts.ts" iget this error

```
error TS5012: Cannot read file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\lib.d.ts': error 
TS5012: Cannot read file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\lib.d.ts': File could 
not be opened.
```

how do i correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your installation is not complete. Just use `npm i -g typescript@latest` to install the latest version of typescript globally on your computer. (By the way: You're using typescript v1 which is really old. The latest version is v4.0)

Comment: i have already done "npm i -g typescript@latest"  but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Resolved the error by manually deleting typescript v1 from my machine.